# Unable to transform `google_dns_record_set` from count to for_each

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

Attempting to upgrade my module to Tf0.12
After running the `terraform 0.12upgrade`, now failing to convert `count` to `for_each`

**Original Module with count**

```
resource "google_dns_record_set" "default" {
  count        = length(var.account_fqdns)
  name         = "${element(var.account_fqdns, count.index)}."
  type         = "A"
  ttl          = 300
  managed_zone = var.dns_managed_zone
  project      = var.dns_project
  rrdatas      = [element(google_compute_address.default2.*.address, count.index)]

}
```

**My New module**

```
resource "google_dns_record_set" "default" {
  for_each     = {for fqdn in var.account_fqdns: fqdn => fqdn}
  name         = each.key
  type         = "A"
  ttl          = 300
  managed_zone = var.dns_managed_zone
  project      = var.dns_project
  rrdatas      = [google_compute_address.default2.*.address]
}
```

I keep running into the error below when I run plan

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 285, in resource "google_dns_record_set" "default":
 285:   rrdatas      = [google_compute_address.default2.*.address]
    |----------------
    | google_compute_address.default2 is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "rrdatas": element 0: string required.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 285, in resource "google_dns_record_set" "default":
 285:   rrdatas      = [google_compute_address.default2.*.address]

This object does not have an attribute named "address".
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem by doing this below

```
rrdatas      = [for ip in google_compute_address.default2: ip.address]
```